# How to get week dates in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing android application. One of my application table has "foo_date" as column name. and data type is TEXT. I have following data in my table

```
primary key  | foo_date  | foo_value
--------------------------------------
1             2013-3-1    100

2             2013-3-2    2

3             2013-3-4    100

4             2013-3-3    1000
```

my requirement is to get data for the current week(i.e. 2013-3-4 to 2013-3-10). When i write below query, i am getting all data except row # 3

```
select * from foo_tbl where foo_date between '2013-3-4' and '2013-3-10';
```

How do I write `sqlite` query so that it includes all data for current week?

Thansk
Chintan

Comment: Storing week number also in DB would have helped a lot.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using at the moment?

Comment: i tried below queries but it doesn't give me the result i am looking for.

Comment: Query 1: select * from foo_tbl where foo_date >= '2013-3-4' and foo_date <= '2013-3-10';  Query 2: select * from foo_tbl where foo_date between '2013-3-4' and '2013-3-10'. None of these queires returns any record.

Comment: I did a similar thing. But I stored the day, month, year in separate columns. It made things easier. You may try that way if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have stored the dates in a format that cannot be compared easily; the character `1` comes before `4`, so `2013-3-10` compares less than `2013-3-4`.

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you should use the ISO date format `yyyy-mm-dd`. With constant field sizes, you can use a query with string comparisons that work:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_date BETWEEN '2013-03-04' AND '2013-03-10'
```

or use a [date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to compute the week:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE strftime('%W', foo_date) = '09'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!! :) i changed format to "yyyy-mm-dd' and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

First, store the dates as standard sqlite time string format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD).
Then, you can use this:

```
select * from foo where strftime('%W', foo_date) == strftime('%W', 'now')
```

to select the rows with the same **week number** as **now**.